# include(PDO.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in YII framework

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, yii

I've got a problem on my running website. few days ago I edited the php.ini file to define the timezone. after two days I notice that my site showing this message "include(PDO.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory" on home page. php.ini file:

```
memory_limit = 128M
post_max_size = 10M
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 10M
date.timezone=America/Phoenix
```

My site link is [SITE LINK](http://quanaceskincare.co.uk)

Can anyone please suggest me how can I fix this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: i guess it's not `php.ini` file error. have you include any `pdo.php` file in your project??

Comment: No... I never added this file.

Comment: my site was up and running.